# Python: How to handle unicode in env variable in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to pass my custom environment variables for the location of my existing application log file directory location in in newly spawn process, Now the problem is that user directory path may contain unicode, depends on user's locale (It can be latin-1)

```
# This Works fine if all the characters are ascii
self.app_log_dir = u'C:\\USERS_CUSTOM_PATCH\\logs\\'

env['APP_LOG_DIR'] = self.app_log_dir 

    p = Popen(
                    cmd, close_fds=False, env=env, stdout=stdout.fileno(),
                    stderr=stderr.fileno(), stdin=stdin.fileno(),
                    creationflags=(CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | DETACHED_PROCESS)
                )

p.start()

##############################

# But path like this fails
self.app_log_dir = u'C:\\USERS_CUSTOM_PATCH\\xx_ÔÔ_xx\\logs\\'
...
...
p.start()
```

Below is the Exception I received from above non-ascii path with popen,

**Exception: environment can only contain strings**

Can anyone suggest work around as I need to handle non-ascii paths in my application?

**Updated:**

pp_log_dir variable is configurable by user, I am unit testing my code and found the issue as user can provide any path in config.py file

Comment: "Unicode paths" doesn't make any sense at all. A file path on disk *must* be bytes. If your path is latin-1, you should use a bytestring encoded in latin-1, surely.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  app_log_dir variable is configurable by user, I am unit testing my code and found the issue as user can provide any path in config.py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is providing a unicode path, encode it to the relevant encoding.

```
env['APP_LOG_DIR'] = self.app_log_dir.encode('latin-1')
```

Comment: Which leaves the question, what the relevant encoding is? Would you go for `locale.getpreferredencoding`?